# Assess which permissions an IAM user would need in advance in order to execute a certain operation

Tags: amazon-web-services, permissions, terraform, airflow, amazon-iam

Is there a way to assess which permissions an IAM user would need **in advance** in order to perform a certain operation on AWS?

Specifically, I'm utilizing an AirFlow [`AWSAthenaOperator`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-amazon/stable/_api/airflow/providers/amazon/aws/operators/athena/index.html) to execute some query against AWS Athena, here is my code:

```
myAthenaTask = AWSAthenaOperator(
    task_id='<MyTaskID>',
    query='<MyQuery>',
    output_location='<s3-output-bucket>',
    database='<my-DB-name>',
    aws_conn_id='<my-connection-name>'
)
```

the annoying problem is that I must execute my task again and again in order to discover all the missing permissions (I simply get AWS access denied errors) - I'm looking for a quick way to discover all the required permissions my user would need without try and fail again and again.

Comment: Not via Airflow. In general it should go the other way... you should be aware of the limitation of the role you have and then work your code accordingly. For example in your case if you are using `output_location` obviously you need also write permissions to S3 specifically for the bucket that you want to write to.

Comment: Thanks @Elad, regardless Airflow,there is any way to find all the required permissions instead of repeatedly try and fail with access denied exceptions?

Comment: I guess the answer is: know what you want to do and then make sure you get IAM role with sufficient permissions to do that. Maybe someone else will have a better answer.

Comment: @Elad it's not easy as you describe it. It turns out that I need multiple permissions to execute a simple operator such as the AWSAthenaOperator.